# How to use sleep into a CLR project?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

How do I replace the following in a CLR project, please?

```
#include <thread>

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(60*100));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(n);
```

Comment: Or, keeping the unit of measure in the code and noting that the question is actually using seconds (but in a weird way), `System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(TimeSpan::FromSeconds(6));`